# cancel place order proccess

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to cancel submit of the checkout form using preventDefault(), but it not work, the alert Test appear and then the page continue the place order process, what I doing wrong?

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function (e) {
     alert("test");
     e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just return false to the ajax call thereby blocking the call. The below code is Tested . . And it's working. Let me know if there is any issues.

```
$( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'checkout_place_order', function() {
    alert( 'submit cancelled!' );
    return false;
});
```